# Photodisintegration of nuclei

Tags: nuclear-physics

I've come across the photodisintegration of iron nuclei in Sec.II of this paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1306.6286.

The computation of the cross section is carried out in the Giant Dipole Resonance, using the dipole interaction and introducing the nuclear polarizability.

Unfortunately many details are missing, can anyone suggest **some good references** where to find these calculations and study the mechanism?
Thank you!